# Default value to select loaded from web service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm carrying a selector from a query to a web service, in this I have no problem. But I need to load a default value, such as "Select value" or something, but I could not get. I leave my code

```
<select ng-model="datas.selectedVal" ng-change="update()">
   <option value="{{org.id}}" ng-repeat="org in organizations">{{org.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Controller :

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: URL_BASE+'getOrganizations/'+sessionService.get("user_id")+'/'+sessionService.get("hash")+"/"})
.success(function(data){
  if(data.Count > 0){
    $scope.organizations = data.Organization;
  }
})
.error(function(){
  //console.log("Error en la conexion al Servidor")
})
.finally(function(){
  $scope.hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Try

```
<select ng-model="datas.selectedVal" ng-change="update()">
<option value=""> Select Value </option>
   <option value="{{org.id}}" ng-repeat="org in organizations">{{org.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Please use ng-options instead of ng-repeat for select box. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: This worked for me, but follow your advice to do with ng-options! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try This Bro :)

```
<select ng-model="datas.selectedVal" ng-options="org.id as org.name for org in organizations"></select>
```